# Writing to a specific dictionary inside a json file Python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a .json file with some information

```
{"items": [{"phone": "testp"}, {"phone": "Test2"}]}
```

I want to add another dictionary into the next available slot in the array with some more information. I have tried many ways however no of them work, has anyone got any ideas?

Comment: You should include what you tried and why it didn't work in your question

Answer (score 0):

```
dictionary["items"].append(new_dictionary)
```

You access key "items" in your dictionary, which is a list of dictionaries, to that list you simply append your new dictionary

Answer (score 0):

You can read the json into a variable using load function.

And then append the value of array using

```
myVar["items"].append(dictVar)
```